# Refused to display a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY' in ionic app on IOS platform

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, iframe, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

Refused to display a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY' in ionic app on IOS platform but the same code is working on the android platform

Comment: Good question! Did you find a solution?

Comment: no I didn't get any solution